# Error in C shell. Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'char **'

Tags: c

I'm an absolute beginner at C. I'm trying to develop a shell where I have a 'history' command which prints out the last 5 commands.

Following is my looping function:

```
void lsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
    printf("> ");
    line = lsh_read_line();
    args = lsh_split_line(line);

    store_history(*line);

    status = lsh_execute(args);

    free(line);
    free(args);
  } while (status);
}
```

And it calls the function to update my global array `history`:

```
void store_history( char *line )
{
   if (history_count < 5) {
        history[history_count++] = strdup( line );
   } else {
        for (unsigned index = 1; index < 5; index++) {
            history[index - 1] = history[index];
        }
        history[4] = strdup( line );
    }

    if (cmdcount < 5){
        cmdcount++;
    }
}
```

The error is stemming from my passing the *lines argument in the function, but I can't fathom why. cmdcount is a global variable that counts the number of elements of history to print later (if less than 5). Rest of my code doesn't seem to have any errors. I ran the shell successfully without the history function.

Comment: Are you sure the `char **` from the title is correct? I would think it should say `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lsh_loop`, the declaration `char *line;` declares `line` to be a pointer to a `char`. So `*line` is a `char`.

Then `store_history(*line);` attempts to pass this `char` to `store_history`.

`store_history` is declared with `void store_history( char *line )`, which declares its parameter to be a pointer to a `char`.

A `char` is not a suitable argument to pass for a parameter that is a pointer to a `char`, so the compiler reports an error.

To pass the command line to `store_history`, change the call to `store_history(line);`.